# how to cluster coreos instances without could-init

Tags: coreos, etcd

so I created three coreos(container linux) instances on aws without user-data/cloud-config.

I did this because my understanding was that cloud-config was just for setting up services and ssh-keys etc and I wanted to do that through other means.

Now I want to know how these three separate instance can be converted to act as a cluster so that updates happen one at a time

basically my question in essence would be **what is the required thing that makes separate instances into a cluster in coreos?**

Comment: erm, launch into an auto-scale group, or put them behind an ELB.

Comment: umm, i auto-scale group adds more instances in case instance fails or is at capacity, and elb load balances between services, but what i am asking is how to make separate instances to act like a cluster in this case specifically for automatic updation provided by coreos, @sudosoul

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just destroy and recreate the machines. Using cloud-init makes this easy, once you get it working just right.

The next best way is going to be writing out a systemd "[drop in](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-systemd-drop-in-units.html#override-only-specific-option)" per machine, with the etcd clustering config. You will need to translate the flags [from this example](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/op-guide/clustering.html#static) into env vars (they follow the same format) and include those env vars in a drop in.

An example looks like:

**/etcd/systemd/system/etcd2.service.d/10-clustering.conf**

```
[Service]
Environment=ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS=http://10.0.0.1:2380
Environment=ETCD_<insert others>
...
```

After applying these, run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` to pick up the changes, and then `sudo systemctl restart etcd2`. You can check if your changes were picked up correctly in the etcd log (it logs all detected env vars) and with `systemctl cat etcd2`, which should list out your drop in.